# Eureka custom row

Tags: eureka-forms

I'm trying to create a custom row in Eureka, but I cannot seem to find a good guide (for newbies like me) that would guide me and make me understand how to do it.

Basically, I want to create the row below using a XIB. It contains 2 labels and an image. Can anybody help make me understand how to do it properly?

Or at least point me to a place where newbies like me can understand how to implement this:

[image: screenshot is here]

Thank you.

Comment: I tried this one (which is very similar to what I want to do): [link](https://blog.xmartlabs.com/2016/09/06/Eureka-custom-row-tutorial/), but with no luck. I think the code needs updating or something. Even by trying the example repo I get lots of compiler errors and I can't seem to find a way to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get too much help from the community this time, but I managed to sort it myself, so I'm going to post the answer here for other newbies like me..

```
final class CartProductRow: Row<CartProductCell>, RowType {
    required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<CartProductCell>(nibName: "CartProductCell")
    }
}

class CartProductCell: Cell<CartProduct>, CellType {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!

    required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        selectionStyle = .none

        productImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        productImage.clipsToBounds = true

        productName.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)

        for label in [productName] {
            label?.textColor = .gray
        }

        height = { return 97 }
    }

    func loadImage(url: String) {
        let url = URL(string:url)
        self.productImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        self.productImage.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.transition(.fade(0.9))])
    }

    override func update() {
        super.update()
        textLabel?.text = nil

        guard let product = row.value else { return }
        if let url = product.smallImageUrl {
            loadImage(url: url)
        }

        productName.text = product.name
    }
}
```